# Copying the last paragraph in a text file

Tags: batch-file, text

I'm interested in writing a batch script that will copy the final block of text in a .txt file that has numerous other blocks of text.  Think of the log file for the executions of a script, but without any consistent content or length.  Each entry is delimited by an empty line.

So for the following document, I would only want to select and copy the final paragraph:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The text itself can vary in length.  The only reliable indicator of what I need is that it will be everything following the final blank line in the document -- in this case, everything following "Duis aute..."

I'm thinking that the outline of the script is going to be something like this, but I'm not at all familiar with batch.  Many thanks for any help you can provide!

```
SET FOO
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (somefile.txt) DO
(IF "%%G"=="" (SET FOO="" )
ELSE (SET FOO==%%G + %FOO%))
ECHO %FOO%>whatever.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the line number of the last empty line
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^$" somefile.txt') do set "skip=skip=%%a"

rem Show all lines after it
for /F "%skip% delims=" %%a in (somefile.txt) do echo %%a
```

Comment: Very cool -- thank you!  Oddly enough, in some text files I've been playing with I only seem to grab the last line of text.  On those files, the first "for" delivers the correct last empty line, but then the subsequent "for" loop only echoes the last line.

Comment: Nevermind -- I wasn't directing the output correctly.  Works great -- thanks!

Comment: May I ask you to select and upvote this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Elegant solution, @Aacini, +1! I fixed a minor issue when `somefile.txt` does not contain any empty lines (`skip=` cannoe be empty)...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "FOO="
type "file.txt" > "file.txt.tmp"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt.tmp"') do if [%%B]==[] (SET "FOO=") else (SET "FOO=!FOO!%%B")
del "file.txt.tmp"
>filepara.txt echo %FOO%
```

This has just one downside, it doesn't echo linebreaks from the original paragraph to the text file.

EDIT:

I found a way to do this that keeps the newlines, by creating a variable containing a newline:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


SET "FOO="
type "file.txt" > "file.txt.tmp"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" eol=¬ %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt.tmp"') do if [%%B]==[] (SET "FOO=") else (SET "FOO=!FOO!%%B!LF!")
del "file.txt.tmp"
>temp.txt echo !FOO!
more temp.txt > paragraph.txt
del temp.txt
```

Note: **You need the two blank lines after set LF for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you!  Here's another, less elegant way to solve the new line problem:

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt.tmp"') do if [%%B]==[] (echo. > tmp.out) else (echo %%B >> tmp.out)
del "file.txt.tmp"
move tmp.out test2.txt

Comment: A question arises, though: what if there are semicolons in the text?  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could set eol to an unused character, will update my answer tomorrow